# Is there any difference between visit 'route' and visit '/route' in Capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara, minitest

The following test would sometimes fail:

```
it 'can create a new item' do 
  visit 'items/new' 
  within 'form#item-form' do 
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Item'
    click_button 'Create'
  end

  current_path.must_equal('/items')
  assert page.has_content?('Item')
end
```

I put a `puts page.html` before the `within` block and found out that sometimes the page would be a clear 'Not found' page. I'm using Capybara's default web driver `Rack::Test`.

Is there any difference between visit 'route' and visit '/route' in Capybara?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there can be a difference in a number of cases depending on things like whether you've specified Capybara.app_host, already visited a url in the current test, etc.  Basically if you want to go to /items/new specify /items/new

You can see the relevant code when using rack-test [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb#L19) and [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L209) .  The other drivers all have similar behavior, so only use relative paths if you really understand what you're doing and need relative paths

On a secondary note,  you should get away from doing direct assertions on current_path.  It will work fine while you're using rack-test since all clicks on submits, links, etc are synchronous - but if/when you move to using a JS capable driver those actions are no longer guaranteed synchronous so you'll end up comparing current_path before it's actually changed.  You should get used to using something along the lines of

```
assert page.has_current_path?('/items')
```

since that will use Capybaras waiting behavior while confirming the current path

Comment: Thanks for the source code links and secondary note, really helpful.